# Is it possible to Inject the result of a producer method in JAX-RS request?

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, inject

I have an utility class :

```
@RequestScoped
public class StatsServicesDataImpl {
    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Target({ METHOD, PARAMETER })
    public @interface Lines {
    }

    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Target({ METHOD, PARAMETER })
    public @interface Versions {
    }

    public StatsServicesDataImpl() {
    }


    @Produces
    @Versions
    @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public String getVersionsAsJsonString() {
        log.debug("CDI calls getVersionsAsJsonString");
    ...
        return json.toString();
    }

    @Produces
    @Lines
    @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public String getLinesAsJsonString() {
        log.debug("CDI calls getLinesAsJsonString");
    ...
        return json.toString();
    }
}
```

And then a JAX-RS class with :

```
@GET
@Path("/versions")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Inject
public Response getVersions(@Versions String versions) {
    log.debug("Endpoint versions :" + versions);
    return Response.ok(versions).build();
}

@GET
@Path("/lines")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Inject
public Response getLines(@Lines String lines) {
    log.debug("Endpoint lines :" + lines);
    return Response.ok(lines).build();
}
```

It doesn't work as expected :( 
I wished that when I call the URL lines, CDI get the lines (@Inject and @Lines) and I have my JSON. 
But when I call lines (http://...../lines) I get :

```
CDI calls getLinesAsJsonString
Endpoint lines :{"lignes":[{"id":97,"idu":1,"nom":"01"},{"id":98,"idu":2,"nom":"02"},{"id":99,"idu":3,"nom":"03"},{"id":100,"idu":4,"nom":"04"},{"id":101,"idu":5,"nom":"05"}]}
CDI calls getVersionsAsJsonString
Endpoint versions :{"versions":[{"id":71,"vdhId":19,"vdrId":18,"vdpId":18,"vdhNom":"Importé le 2017-08-10 Septembre 2017 V1","vdhDateExp":"Sep 1, 2017 12:00:00 AM","jexDateDeb":"Sep 1, 2017 12:00:00 AM","jexDateFin":"Aug 10, 2018 12:00:00 AM","downloadedDate":"mai 1, 2018"}]}
Endpoint lines :
```

And when I call versions :

```
CDI calls getLinesAsJsonString
Endpoint lines :{"lignes":[{"id":97,"idu":1,"nom":"01"},{"id":98,"idu":2,"nom":"02"},{"id":99,"idu":3,"nom":"03"},{"id":100,"idu":4,"nom":"04"},{"id":101,"idu":5,"nom":"05"}]}
CDI calls getVersionsAsJsonString
Endpoint versions :{"versions":[{"id":71,"vdhId":19,"vdrId":18,"vdpId":18,"vdhNom":"Importé le 2017-08-10 Septembre 2017 V1","vdhDateExp":"Sep 1, 2017 12:00:00 AM","jexDateDeb":"Sep 1, 2017 12:00:00 AM","jexDateFin":"Aug 10, 2018 12:00:00 AM","downloadedDate":"mai 1, 2018"}]}
Endpoint versions :
```

Same result :( As if both producer methods were called ...

Any idea how to combine JAX-RS and CDI so I can inject the result of a request (produced by CDI) in the response of the Rest-request ?

Comment: Funny (?) : when I Inject @Lines String lines as a field (idem with versions) it works as expected. I still don't understand why it doesn't work in the first place :(

Comment: I would double check for any typos in your code. It seems really awkward that it works with field injection and not with producer one. Besides in your output, the call to `getLines` always comes first, even when you want versions - try debugging when are the producers invoked.